# iOS app (Hang) Freeze in iPhone 7 but Work in Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, freeze

I have developed an iOS app on Swift 3. It is a car tracking app. Car shown on map with animation from server data location set (API parse). 
I have use  Timer for animation time distance. **New problem has encountered that after some time animation car in map the app become hang (freeze) for iPhone 7 and for iPhone 4s I got “Lost connection to x iPhone” at debug mode. But work good in Simulator.**

I search a lot for solving that. Some one said Thread issue, memory issue … But nothing can help me. Code skeleton given bellow.

```
@IBAction func submitRecordedAction(_ sender: UIButton){
       recordation()
 }

func recordation(){
 let parameters = [ ---- ] as [String : Any]

            loc.getRecordedLocations(para: parameters, success: { (status, msg) in

                            let poiSearchQue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.poiSearchQue", qos: .utility)

                            poiSearchQue.async {

                                self.parsePOI()

                            }

                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0, execute: {

                          self.recordedDataShow()

                    })

            }, failure: { (msg) in

            })

}

func self.recordedDataShow(){
     //Calling timer from here according to location array  
 }
```

Comment: this issue can arise due to memory leakage. Please apply break point at didReceiveMemoryWarning() and see if the app enters in it

Comment: Run the app and wait for the freeze. Once you observing the freeze press the pause button in the bottom console panel. Then you can observe the current running thread in the left panel which will give you some idea of what causing the freeze.

Comment: Hakikat Singh you are right. But what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the info.plist, if you are using microphone, camera, or photo library on your app, you have to add these permissions on info.plist in order for your app to work perfectly.

here are few examples:

if you are using camera on you app: key **NSCameraUsageDescription**
or if you are using photo library: **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**

Comment: I have already add this

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Allow us to use camera to capture the image</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Allow this permission to use photo album</string>

Problem not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem has solved. The problem is that GMSPlolyLines overlap. After solving this there is no problem now.